# Erro NoReverseMatch no Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, aplicação-web, django, django-templates

Olá! Estudando sobre **Django** e desenvolvendo nesse Framework, me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> **NoReverseMatch** at / Reverse for 'exibirURL' with arguments '('',)' **not
>   found**. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['perfis/(?P\d+)$']

Para melhor entendimento da situação, segue abaixo minhas rotas (***urls.py***), meu ***.html*** e minhas funções de view (***views.py***)

***index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ConnectedIn</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    {% if keyPerfil %}
      <ul>
        {% for perfil in keyPerfil %}
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'exibirURL' keyPerfil.id %}">{{keyPerfil.nome}} / {{keyPerfil.email}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>Nenhum perfil encontrado</p>
    {% endif %}
  </body>

</html>
```

***views.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from perfis.models import Perfil

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'keyPerfil': Perfil.objects.all()})

def exibir(request, perfil_id):
    # necessario receber o parametro perfil_id, passado no urls.py

    perfil = Perfil.objects.get(id=perfil_id)

    return render(request, 'perfil.html', {'keyPerfil': perfil})
```

***urls.py:***

```
from django.urls import re_path
from perfis.views import index, exibir

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', index, name='indexURL'),
    re_path(r'^perfis/(?P<perfil_id>\d+)$', exibir, name='exibirURL'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu `for` em index.html vc deveria chamar `perfil.id` e não `keyPerfil.id`

A linha ficaria assim:

```
<a href="{% url 'exibirURL' perfil.id %}">{{perfil.nome}} / {{perfil.email}}</a>
```